# compare cpuusage value using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command

How can i comapre the CPU usage value using shell script, i get a error as [: =: unary operator expected at the line `if [ $message -ne "" ]`

```
   #!/bin/sh

    expected_cpuusage="95"
    cpu_usage=`top -n 1 -b|grep Cpu|awk '{print $2}'|cut -d"%" -f1""`
    message=""
    if [ $cpu_usage -gt $expected_cpuusage ]    ##{x%?}
    then
       echo "CPU usage exceeded";
       if [ $message -ne "" ]
       then
         message="$message\n\nCPU usage exceeded configured usage limit \nCurrent CPU usage is $cpu_usage\nConfigured CPU usage is $expected_cpuusage";
       else
         message="CPU usage exceeded configured usage limit \nCurrent CPU usage is $cpu_usage\nConfigured CPU usage is $expected_cpuusage";
       fi ;
    fi
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `top` is hardly the right approach. Try `man uptime` or read directly from `/proc` if your architecture has that.

Comment: I agree with @tripleee. Here's a better method to get CPU utilization: `bc<<<"scale=3;$(ps ax -o pcpu= | sort -n | xargs printf '+ %s' | cut -c 2- | bc) / $(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)"` (presumes bash and a Linux `/proc/`). This gives average over all cores, so a 50% utilization of one core on a dual core system would return `25.000`. The "CPU utilization" part should be fairly portable, just the "How many cores?" part is not.

Comment: One nice thing about this approach is that you can drop `scale=3;` and be sure that you now get back a non-floating-point number, which you can use with `-gt` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` is a redirection operator.  You want `-gt`

```
if [ $cpu_usage -gt $expected_cpuusage ]
```

This requires that $cpu_usage look like an integer and will fail and generate an error if it does not.  (ie, if it contains characters other than 0-9.  -gt does not compare floating point values, so strings that contain '.' will not work.)  For floating point comparisons, use expr:

```
if expr $cpu_usage \> $expected_cpuusage > /dev/null; then
```

There are slicker ways to do this comparison using bash builtins like [[, but these constructs limit the portability of the script.
The other error you are seeing occurs when you use an empty string.  Try using quotes:

```
if [ "$message" -ne "" ]
```

but it is much clearer to use:

```
if [ -n "$message" ]
```

Comment: still the same error, i have changed my question too for the if condition

Comment: after changing it i also get this integer expression expected

Comment: The fundamental problem is still the lack of quotes, as explained in l0b0's answer.

Comment: @triplee, No the fundamental problem originally was that he was using > instead of -gt.  When the question was edited to use -gt, the fundamental problem became attempting to use test to compare floating point values.  The lack of quotes is secondary.

Comment: The question asks about `-ne` and there is no indication that it was edited.

Comment: @triplee.. look at the first comment to my answer.  There is a time window during which questions (and answers) can be edited during which no history is retained.

Answer (score 2):

[Use more quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.24foo_.3D_.22bar.22_.5D):

```
if [ "$message" -ne "" ]
```

Otherwise empty strings will mess up the expression.

Even better:

```
if [ -n "$message" ]
```